# Stop a file from being uploaded in Dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone for the uploading on MP3 and WAV files. I have set an upper limit file size of 100MB but for MP3's I want to set a limit of 15MB.

I can check the file size as soon as the add the file using the `this.on("addedfile")` event listener, but I can't seem to find a way to fail the upload. I'm aware that I can remove the file from the uploader before it uploads, but I don't want to remove it, just fail with an error. How can I do this?

```
$dropzone.dropzone({
            maxFilesize: 100,
            maxFiles: (limit) ? limit : 25,
            acceptedFiles: 'audio/mp3, audio/wav',
            init: function () {
                this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                    if (file.type == 'audio/mp3' && (file.size / (1000 * 1000)) > 15) {
                        console.log('MP3 too big');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of [How to cancel/abort upload in Dropzone.js if condition is not fulfilled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829924/how-to-cancel-abort-upload-in-dropzone-js-if-condition-is-not-fulfilled) Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829924/how-to-cancel-abort-upload-in-dropzone-js-if-condition-is-not-fulfilled#23835326) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case you should use the `accept` instead of the `addedfile` event, http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-accept

```
$dropzone.dropzone({
    maxFilesize: 100,
    maxFiles: (limit) ? limit : 25,
    acceptedFiles: 'audio/mp3, audio/wav',
    accept: function(file, done) {
        if (file.type == 'audio/mp3' && (file.size / (1000 * 1000)) > 15) {
            done('MP3 too big');
        } else {
            done();
        }
    }        
});
```

Comment: not possible, as written in the official docs: This function will not be called if the file is too big or doesn't match the mime types.